# macro pulls incorrect data from txt file

Tags: excel, vba

Macro pulls incorrect data from txt files. I have a code that loops through several hundred files pulling timestamps for start time and Diagnose time and pastes them into column A and B. The time stamp for start time pulls correctly but the time stamp for Diagnose does not. Instead the first line of text in the txt file is pulled and pasted into column B. A sample of the input txt Log file looks like this, there are hundreds of other time stamps in the txt log file but the two time stamps I care about are start and [irp] Diagnose

```
      +version=LogbookPlus 1.7.23
      +site=
      +lastedit=2019-08-31 17:19:31.289
      +description=SRC - LSA-0251 error
      +number=1282
      +so=51657136
      +toolowner=
      +init=2019-08-30 08:40:38.360
      +start=2019-08-30 08:25
      +end=2019-08-30 09:45
      +down=Unscheduled
      +account=Source
      +rooterror=LSA-0251
      +subsystem=ILP-DC-PQ
      +assy=Dose & power performance
      +work=2019-08-30|08:39| [IRP] Diagnose
      +work=2019-08-30|08:41| Start streaming
      +work=2019-08-30|09:03| Conditioning
      +work=2019-08-30|09:04| Standby
```

Here is my code

```
Sub FindTimeStamps()

Dim TextFile As Integer
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileContent As String
Dim MyFolder As String, MyFile As String

'Open Diaglouge box prompting user to choose folder path

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    Err.Clear
End With

'Create a new object for files in that folder and apply for/loop

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.getFolder(MyFolder)
Dim fls As Object
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
For Each fls In objFolder.Files
'File Path of Text File

MyFile = MyFolder & "\" & fls.Name

'Determine the next file number available for use by the Fileopen function

TextFile = FreeFile
'open the text file

Debug.Print CurDir
Open MyFile For Input As #1

'Store file content inside a variable

 Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    Text = Text & textline
Loop

Close #1
 'Find Time Stamp Data from txt file
  Dtime = Diagnose
  Diagnose = InStr(1, Text, Dtime)
  dt = Mid(Text, Diagnose + 1, 17)
  Sttime = InStr(Text, "+start=")

'Paste obtained Time Stamp into excel Cells

Range("A" & i + 1).Value = Mid(Text, Sttime + 7, 16)
Range("B" & i + 1).Value = dt
i = i + 1

Text = ""
Next
End Sub
```

if I do not hard code the Diagnose variable and instead do a user input such as

```
Find = InputBox("which word")
Open Text For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
   Input #1, Text
   If InStr(1, Text, Find) > 0 Then
      idx = InStr(1, Text, "=")
      dt = Mid(Text, idx + 1, 17)
   Exit Do
End If
Loop
```

This was suggested by another user and the code works and pulls the correct time stamp. The Drawback to this is that I have to keep typing in Diagnose for every single file in the folder which is not ideal. Im still learning VBA so I'm not just looking for a solution but also a reason why the hard coded variable does not pull data correctly. Thanks any help is much appreciated

Here is the output of the macro I get in excel when I use the Hard coded variable for Diagnose, there are no time stamps in column b for diagnose it just pulls the first line of the input txt file for reason I do not understand

```
          Column A          Column B
          8/28/2019 14:29   version=LogbookPl
          8/29/2019 5:38    version=LogbookPl
          8/30/2019 8:25    version=LogbookPl
```

Comment: It is not very clear as you are not exposing which one is the input data and which one is your expected output. Anyhow, if you need to work always with "Diagnose", instead to place a InputBox, just set Find="Diagnose".

Comment: Sorry I just posted the output I keep getting the first column is the time stamp of the start time and the second Column is supposed to be the time stamp of diagnose but instead is retrieves version=logbook. Also I’ve already tried setting a hard variable such as find=“diagnose” but it doesn’t find the word diagnose in the text file

Comment: That´s why, could you edit and place a small example of your input data?

Comment: I edited the question to point out the input data and the output that I keep getting with my current code

Comment: ahhh that makes sense. So i need to somehow specify i want to find Diagnose within the [IRP] Diagnose string in the txt file input and pull out the time stamp associated with it

Comment: Another issue, your expected output is just the time?

Comment: Yes Just the date and time that makes up the time stamp

Comment: You can do this fairly easily with Power Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub FindTimeStamps()

Dim TextFile As Integer
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileContent As String
Dim MyFolder As String, MyFile As String

'Open Diaglouge box prompting user to choose folder path

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    Err.Clear
End With

'Create a new object for files in that folder and apply for/loop

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.getFolder(MyFolder)
Dim fls As Object
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
For Each fls In objFolder.Files
'File Path of Text File

MyFile = MyFolder & "\" & fls.Name

'Determine the next file number available for use by the Fileopen function

TextFile = FreeFile
'open the text file

Debug.Print CurDir
Open MyFile For Input As #1

'Store file content inside a variable

Do Until EOF(1)
    Input #1, textline
    Text = textline
    If (InStr(Text, "+start=") <> 0) Then
        Sttime = InStr(Text, "+start=")
        Range("A" & i + 1).Value2 = Mid(Text, Sttime + 7, 16)
        i = i + 1
    End If
    If (InStr(Text, "| [IRP] Diagnose") <> 0) Then
        dt = InStr(Text, "| [IRP] Diagnose")
        Range("B" & i).Value2 = Mid(Text, dt - 16, 10) & " " & Mid(Text, dt - 5, 5)
    End If
    If (Range("B" & i).Value2 = "") And (Range("A" & i).Value2 <> "") Then _
                                        Range("B" & i).Value2 = "No Diagnose"
Loop
Close #1

Next
End Sub
```

With the files you sent me it is working. Please check

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

I check that one in a couple of files and it works.

```
Sub FindTimeStamps()

Dim TextFile As Integer
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileContent As String
Dim MyFolder As String, MyFile As String

'Open Diaglouge box prompting user to choose folder path

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    Err.Clear
End With

'Create a new object for files in that folder and apply for/loop

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.getFolder(MyFolder)
Dim fls As Object
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
For Each fls In objFolder.Files
'File Path of Text File

MyFile = MyFolder & "\" & fls.Name

'Determine the next file number available for use by the Fileopen function

TextFile = FreeFile
'open the text file

Debug.Print CurDir
Open MyFile For Input As #1

'Store file content inside a variable

Do Until EOF(1)
    Input #1, textline
    Text = textline
    If (InStr(Text, "+start=") <> 0) Then
        Sttime = InStr(Text, "+start=")
        Range("A" & i + 1).Value = Mid(Text, Sttime + 7, 16)
    End If
    If (InStr(Text, "Diagnose") <> 0) Then
        dt = InStr(Text, "Diagnose")
        Range("B" & i + 1).Value = Mid(Text, dt - 24, 10) & " " & Mid(Text, dt - 13, 5)
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop

Close #1

Next
End Sub
```

Hope it helps

With the Input you gave: (I just repeat it)

```
+version=LogbookPlus 1.7.23
 +start=2019-08-30 08:25
 +work=2019-08-30|08:41| [IRP] Diagnose
 +work=2019-09-08|14:32| DAS power on
 +work=2019-09-08|14:33| linux boot
 +version=LogbookPlus 1.7.23
 +start=2019-08-30 08:25
 +work=2019-08-30|08:41| [IRP] Diagnose
 +work=2019-09-08|14:32| DAS power on
 +work=2019-09-08|14:33| linux boot
 +version=LogbookPlus 1.7.23
 +start=2019-08-30 08:25
 +work=2019-08-30|08:41| [IRP] Diagnose
 +work=2019-09-08|14:32| DAS power on
 +work=2019-09-08|14:33| linux boot
 +version=LogbookPlus 1.7.23
 +start=2019-08-30 08:25
 +work=2019-08-30|08:41| [IRP] Diagnose
 +work=2019-09-08|14:32| DAS power on
 +work=2019-09-08|14:33| linux boot
```

I am gettting:

[This log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ik5y.png)

Is it this what you are looking for?

Comment: unfortunately that wont work because the rest of the log entries also have  +work in front of the time stamp. I edited the question again to reflect this

Comment: Ok, so with the new information, I already the answer and that one should works. I count 32 characters from Diagnose... just check.

Comment: running your exact code i receive a Run-time error '1004': application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Should be `Mid(Text, dt - 24, 16)` instead of `Mid(Text, dt - 31, 17)`, I will edit it. I add 2 conditions to avoid errors in remaining lines. If you want to receive the same format, instead of `Mid(Text, dt - 24, 16)`, place `Mid(Text, dt - 24, 10) & " " & Mid(Text, dt - 13, 5)`

Comment: It returns a bad argument, if I comment out the Mid(Text, dt - 24, 16), or Mid(Text, dt - 24, 10) & " " & Mid(Text, dt - 13, 5) the program runs but obviously won’t print the values to the column

Comment: the log you generated is what im looking for. When i run the code i generate a run-time error '5': invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: I figured out what my program is doing. It is finding Diagnose but is pulling everything after for example the log has +work=2019-08-30|08:41| [IRP] Diagnose
+work=2019-08-30|08:41| [MNPWR] Arrival              
 what its doing is pulling        agnose+work=2019-08-30|08:41| [MNP  as one full sting. if i try to us the Mid(Text, dt -24, 16) vba returns an error so for some reason its having an issue with the -24 portion of Mid

Comment: Could you add a longer  section of your file? I can not replicate it...

Comment: Added a longer section. all the logs have the same format and i have a folder with dozens of logs in it. I want the code to prompt the user to select which folder they want and it automatically pulls start time and diagnose time and populates column A and B with the information.

Comment: Ok, let me duplicate it

Comment: Again, that one is working for me. One question... how many characters have your got from the beginning of the line to the first character?

Comment: [Input] at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNMUU.png and [Output] at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWlQc.png

Comment: Regarding the -24 option, that is the one I am using, the problem is that it should find, exactly, the beginning of the date/time. If it goes to "=" or "|" then you have this vba error. Maybe you could avoid that one if you use "i + 1).Value = ", you use "i + 1).Value2 = "

Comment: Could you try changing the diagnose time on two of the files you created. when I run the code it pulls the start time and diagnose time from the first file then gives the run time error 5 prompt. I wonder if this is because some files might not have a diagnose time as in it was not properly recorded. I wonder if i can just put a if statement in the code to just populate column b if diagnose time is present if not then populate 0

Comment: can i send you a full txt file. I created a file with the snippet of information i posted here and duplicated it three time like you and it works. but when i use it on a full file i get the run time error

Comment: davidbodego@gmail.com

Comment: Sure, it is possible to do. If you are looking for it, I can place a condition so, if there is no Diagnose line, it will return "No Diagnose" or whatever you need.